# java.nio.Path: How do I force java to resolve `..` when Path is relative to the current directory?

Tags: java, file, io

Suppose I have the following directory structure:

```
| baz/
|-- | foo/
|   |-- bar.txt
```

And that I run my program so that the current directory is `baz/`. If I define a Path like this:

```java
var foo = Path.of("../foo/bar.txt");
```

I want to present this path to the user, but when I just print the path out as is it includes the `..`, like this:

```
../foo/bar.txt
```

How do I get it to present this path like this instead?

```
baz/foo/bar.txt
```

Comment: **`Path#toAbolutePath()`.** Relative paths are dangerous though, like different in IDE as stand-alone. The `resolve` methods are better.

Comment: `Path#toAbolutePath()` prints out the entire absolute path, which is not what I want. I simply want to resolve the `..` into the actual folder's name.

Comment: You can use [**`relativize`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#relativize(java.nio.file.Path)) for that.